# python module 'pandas' has no attribute 'plotting'

Tags: python, pandas

I am a beginner of Python. I follow the machine learning course of Intel. And I encounter some troubles in coding. I run the code below in Jupyter and it raises an `AttributeError`.

```
import pandas as pd
step_data = [3620, 7891, 9761,3907, 4338, 5373]
step_counts = pd.Series(step_data,name='steps')
print(step_counts)
```

> AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'plotting'

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16322) then. Can you check if you have a (maybe empty) PyQt4 directory in your site-packages? Removing that should fix it. Refer to this
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16536

Comment: I think your error is not in this piece of code that you shared. I am assuming this because I don't see any call to the 'plotting' attribute from the pandas. But I am not familiar with panda, tho.

Comment: I can't find PyQt4 in my computer.....

Comment: PyQt5?= is present?

Answer (score 4):

In your terminal type

```
pip install plotting.
```

Comment: This worked after following the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60818229/3832970).

Answer (score 3):

Update your pandas version using following command

```
pip install --upgrade pandas
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute **pip** command directly in Jupyter notebook, run the following:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install --upgrade pandas
```

The above code makes sure that the package is installed for the same version of python installed with Jupyter notebook.

In some situations the below command also works:

```
!pip install --upgrade pandas
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating pandas usually corrects this error. Hence update your version of pandas and the error should be solved. Additionally, your code snippet does work.

[image: The code snippet with the latest version of pandas]