# Unable to import pandas (pandas._libs.window.aggregations)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I've lost a couple of hours trying to solve this so I guess it's time to ask someone/somehwere.

I (think) I have uninstalled everything related to `python` and than installed again. I just installed `python` most recent version and used `pip` to install `pandas`. I also try to install it with `anaconda` but the error persists. I've also tried installing directly from github but was unsuccessful. I'm using windows 10.

```
C:\Users\m>python -V
Python 3.8.2

C:\Users\m>pip install pandas
Collecting pandas
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/07/12/5a087658337a230f4a77e3d548c847e81aa59b332cdd8ddf5c8d7f11c4a1/pandas-1.0.3-cp38-cp38-win32.whl (7.6MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 7.6MB 3.3MB/s
Collecting pytz>=2017.2 (from pandas)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e7/f9/f0b53f88060247251bf481fa6ea62cd0d25bf1b11a87888e53ce5b7c8ad2/pytz-2019.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (509kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 512kB 3.2MB/s
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.6.1 (from pandas)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d4/70/d60450c3dd48ef87586924207ae8907090de0b306af2bce5d134d78615cb/python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 235kB 6.4MB/s
Collecting numpy>=1.13.3 (from pandas)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5d/b3/f3543d9919baa11afc24adc029a25997821f0376e5fab75fdc16e13469db/numpy-1.18.2-cp38-cp38-win32.whl (10.8MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 10.8MB 6.4MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\m\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.6.1->pandas) (1.13.0)
Installing collected packages: pytz, python-dateutil, numpy, pandas
Successfully installed numpy-1.18.2 pandas-1.0.3 python-dateutil-2.8.1 pytz-2019.3
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

C:\Users\m>python
Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 22:45:29) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import (
  File "C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper, NamedAgg
  File "C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.generic import DataFrameGroupBy, NamedAgg, SeriesGroupBy
  File "C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py", line 60, in <module>
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
  File "C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 124, in <module>
    from pandas.core.series import Series
  File "C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4572, in <module>
    Series._add_series_or_dataframe_operations()
  File "C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 10349, in _add_series_or_dataframe_operations
    from pandas.core.window import EWM, Expanding, Rolling, Window
  File "C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.core.window.ewm import EWM  # noqa:F401
  File "C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window\ewm.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pandas._libs.window.aggregations as window_aggregations
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing aggregations: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I finally ended up trying a slightly older version of pandas to resolve this exact error. The default install was 1.0.3, so I backed up a couple of release points:

```
pip uninstall pandas
pip install pandas==1.0.1
```

Then I could import pandas without error

Comment: FYI: I filed this as a bug report at the Pandas' Github

Comment: i haven't needed this on all Win10 installations, but this totally works on those that get this error. thanks!

Comment: I had a similar issue... downgrading from 1.5 to 1.3 resolved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me that Pandas 1.0.3 is not installing the DLLs in the 
"Lib\site-packages\pandas_libs\window" folder.

For me this worked:

Installing Pandas 1.0.1.

Then copying the these two DLLs from the folder somewhere safe

```
concrt140.dll
msvcp140.dll
```

Now update to Pandas 1.0.3

After that, the DLLs are missing.
Move them back to the folder and the import runs fine.

Comment: I had another issue after following these instructions related to `plotting` module and after  following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55038175/3832970), after running `pip install plotting`, pandas got finally imported in Python 3.8.