# Trying first program of ML in python using iris data set

Tags: python, pandas

Trying just the following code in beginning to make sure that necessary API is installed and accessible.

```
from pandas import read_csv
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
from matplotlib import pyplot
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis importLinearDiscriminantAnalysis
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.svm import SVC


print("Testing of installation successful..Go Ahead.")
```

However, getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\test_ml.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pandas import read_csv
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import (
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper, NamedAgg
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.generic import DataFrameGroupBy, NamedAgg, SeriesGroupBy
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py", line 60, in <module>
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 124, in <module>
    from pandas.core.series import Series
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4572, in <module>
    Series._add_series_or_dataframe_operations()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 10349, in _add_series_or_dataframe_operations
    from pandas.core.window import EWM, Expanding, Rolling, Window
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.core.window.ewm import EWM  # noqa:F401
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window\ewm.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pandas._libs.window.aggregations as window_aggregations
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing aggregations: The specified module could not be found.
```

Kindly provide me the solution.I am using Python 3.8.2 and IDLE 3.8.32

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: Seems like this was asked pretty recently and has an accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60763529/unable-to-import-pandas-pandas-libs-window-aggregations

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to import pandas (pandas.\_libs.window.aggregations)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60763529/unable-to-import-pandas-pandas-libs-window-aggregations)

Comment: Got the solution...Uninstalled pandas 1.0.3 and installed 1.0.1. It works!pip uninstall pandas
pip install pandas==1.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Seems it is an issue with the latest version of pandas.

Try installing an older version:

```
pip uninstall pandas
pip install pandas==1.0.1
```

Original answer:
[Unable to import pandas (pandas._libs.window.aggregations)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60763529/unable-to-import-pandas-pandas-libs-window-aggregations)