# ImportError: when I use quandl module in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror, quandl

ImportError: when I use quandl module in python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vopl1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\vopl1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\workspace\python\stock-lab\agent\quandl.py", line 1, in <module>
    import quandl
  File "C:\Users\vopl1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\quandl\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .model.database import Database
  File "C:\Users\vopl1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\quandl\model\database.py", line 5, in <module>
    import quandl.model.dataset
  File "C:\Users\vopl1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\quandl\model\dataset.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .data import Data
  File "C:\Users\vopl1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\quandl\model\data.py", line 1, in <module>
    from quandl.operations.data_list import DataListOperation
  File "C:\Users\vopl1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\quandl\operations\data_list.py", line 1, in <module>
    from quandl.model.data_list import DataList
  File "C:\Users\vopl1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\quandl\model\data_list.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .data_mixin import DataMixin
  File "C:\Users\vopl1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\quandl\model\data_mixin.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\vopl1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import (
  File "C:\Users\vopl1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper, NamedAgg
  File "C:\Users\vopl1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.generic import DataFrameGroupBy, NamedAgg, SeriesGroupBy
  File "C:\Users\vopl1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py", line 60, in <module>
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
  File "C:\Users\vopl1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 124, in <module>
    from pandas.core.series import Series
  File "C:\Users\vopl1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4572, in <module>
    Series._add_series_or_dataframe_operations()
  File "C:\Users\vopl1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 10349, in _add_series_or_dataframe_operations
    from pandas.core.window import EWM, Expanding, Rolling, Window
  File "C:\Users\vopl1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.core.window.ewm import EWM  # noqa:F401
  File "C:\Users\vopl1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window\ewm.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pandas._libs.window.aggregations as window_aggregations
ImportError: DLL load failed: 지정된 모듈을 찾을 수 없습니다.
```

I did several things, but I don't know why the module was not available

1. I installed quandl
   as followed :

```
pip install quandl
```

2. I made my under python code

```
import quandl

quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = '@@@@@@@@@@@@@@'
data = quandl.get('BCHARTS/BITFLYERUSD', start_date='2019-03-07', end_date='2020-05-02')

print(data)
```

3. I call my pthon code

```
python -m myPythonCode
```

and then, I saw the error.

So I deleted and installed, but failed.

So I installed as followed :

```
pip3 install quandl
```

this is still failed.

if uninstall quandl and then call my python code, I can see error :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'quandl'
```

Plz, Help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to import pandas (pandas.\_libs.window.aggregations)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60763529/unable-to-import-pandas-pandas-libs-window-aggregations)

Answer (score 1):

When the error is DLL related, many times it can be resolved by installing the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable that is most likely missing.

[Microsoft Visual C++](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I install Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2019. This is available. Thank you!!